# Android:Open iframe of WebView in Browser/YouTube App

Tags: android, json, iframe, webview

I have some JSON content of a blog which i am displaying using `loadDataWithBaseURL` in `WebView`. Many articles of this blog have embedded youtube/vimeo videos.

Currently, all the videos are played inside the webview itself.

What i want to achieve is, when the user clicks to Play the Video, he should get the popup "Complete Action Using" Browser or YouTube App. In short, i dont want the videos to be played inside the webview of app.

I found questions where everyone was trying to avoid this popup.. Dont' know why i am not getting it.

Here is my code

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    String strTitle = null;
    String strURL = null;
    String strContent = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container, false);

        strTitle = getArguments().getString("title");
        strURL = getArguments().getString("url");
        strContent = getArguments().getString("content");

        String contToDisplay = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset='UTF-8' /></head><body><style type='text/css'> img{width:80%;} .wp-image-42223{display:none;}</style>" + strContent+"</body></html>";

        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        WebView desc = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);


        WebSettings ws = desc.getSettings();
        ws.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        ws.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        ws.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

        ws.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
        title.setText(strTitle);
        // desc.loadData(contToDisplay, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
        desc.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank",strContent,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        return view;
    }
}
```

any solution that wold make the videos load in browser or YouTube App would help.

**NOTE**

The content i am displaying in webview is in HTML format with iframe as one of the elements. Here is the sample data:

```
"<p>Some text</p>
 <p><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/q7uBAtaK15I\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe>   </p>
<p>some more text</p>
```

This entire content is displayed in webview. What i want to achieve is when someone clicks on iframe, he should be prompted to `complete action using` that is, the person shd not be allowed to play the video in webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this using regex.

Here is what i did

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container, false);

    strTitle = getArguments().getString("title");
    strURL = getArguments().getString("url");
    strContent = getArguments().getString("content");

    contToDisplay = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset='UTF-8' /><script type='text/javascript'></script></head><body><style type='text/css'> img{width:80%;} .wp-image-42223{display:none;} </style>" + strContent+"</body></html>";

    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView authorName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auth);
   desc = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);


    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    WebSettings ws = desc.getSettings();
      ws.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    ws.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    ws.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    ws.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

    ws.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
    title.setText(strTitle);

    final String s = strContent;
    final String regex = "(?<=<iframe src=\")[^\"]*";
    final String regex2 = "<\\s*iframe[^>]*><\\s*/\\s*iframe>";
    p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);
    m = p.matcher(s);
     m2 = p2.matcher(s);
    evaluate(s,contToDisplay,this);
    desc.loadData(value, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
    return view;
   }

     String evaluate(String token,String defaultValue, DetailFragment context){
     value=null;
    Matcher matcher=p.matcher(token);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        iframeURL=matcher.group();
        String newURL = "<a href=\"" + iframeURL + "\">Watch the Video Here</a>";
        value = m2.replaceAll(newURL);
    }
    if (value == null) {
        value=defaultValue;
    }
    return value != null ? value : "";
}
```

Might help someone with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.we are loading a new url load in the correct native app.

```
desc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                                                String url)
        {

            return true;
        }

                });
```

Comment: Still the video plays in the webview only.. did i just need to add the lines you suggested??

Comment: yeah you had to add that lines alone.

you can try this also inside shouldoverrideurlloading

 if(url.contains("http://www.youtube.com")){ // Could be cleverer and use a regex
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); // Leave webview and use browser
        }

Comment: I added your code but still the video plays in webview only. I have updated the question so you can know what exactly i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
desc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                                            String url)
    {
    if(url.contains("youtube.com")){ 
     // Could be cleverer and use a regex return                                    
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }
    return true;

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the links are embedded in an iframe (as the title suggested) you have to set a WebChromeClient to your webview and override the onCreateWindow-method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow (WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

    WebView targetWebView = new WebView(view.getContext()); 
    targetWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            //simple url matching
            if (url.contains("youtube.com") == true) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                view.getContex().startActivity(i);
            }
            view.stopLoading();
        }
    });
    WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
    transport.setWebView(targetWebView);
    resultMsg.sendToTarget();
    return true;
}
```

And at the websettings of your webview, you have to set:

```
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

Comment: I added `WebChromeClient` but still the video plays in webview only. I have updated the question so you can know what exactly i am trying to achieve

Comment: @Swapna: Is the html under your control? If yes, try to surround your iframe with a-tag: <a href =\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/q7uBAtaK15I\"><iframe>....</frame></a>, then match and catch the url in shouldOverride-method and trigger an intent as i suggested above.